# "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages"

Tags: 8, webforms, composer

Last time I used composer on my project was to update drupal core from 8.6.2 to 8.6.3 using `composer update drupal/core webflo/drupal-core-require-dev --with-dependencies` and to update the webform module from 8.x-5.0-rc24 to 8.x-5.0-rc26 using `composer require 'drupal/webform:^5.0'` and after both successful updates, my website is working perfectly but any Composer command I use is returning the same error.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package algolia/places 1.13.0 is satisfiable by algolia/places[1.13.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package codemirror/codemirror 5.41.0 is satisfiable by codemirror/codemirror[5.41.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 3
    - The requested package jquery/inputmask 4.0.2 is satisfiable by jquery/inputmask[4.0.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 4
    - The requested package jquery/intl-tel-input 14.0.4 is satisfiable by jquery/intl-tel-input[14.0.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 5
    - The requested package jquery/timepicker 1.11.14 is satisfiable by jquery/timepicker[1.11.14] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

The Composer commands I tried so far are:

- `composer update`
- `composer update drupal/core webflo/drupal-core-require-dev --with-dependencies`
- `composer require "webflo/drupal-finder ~1.0.0"`

As I remember, the following packages are used by the Webform module and this module is updated to the latest stable release version.

- algolia/places
- codemirror/codemirror
- jquery/inputmask
- jquery/intl-tel-input
- jquery/timepicker

I have tried both the solutions mentioned in [Conflict between package requirements when updating to Drupal 8.4](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/247644/conflict-between-package-requirements-when-updating-to-drupal-8-4) but with no success at all.

What is going on?

**UPDATE #1:**

Here is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "drupal-composer/drupal-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "role": ""
        }
    ],
    "repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        "drupal": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "algolia/places": "1.10.0",
        "ckeditor/autogrow": "4.10.0",
        "ckeditor/codemirror": "v1.17.7",
        "ckeditor/fakeobjects": "4.10.0",
        "ckeditor/image": "4.10.0",
        "ckeditor/link": "4.10.0",
        "codemirror/codemirror": "5.40.0",
        "composer/installers": "^1.2",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6.5",
        "drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold": "^2.5",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^1.24",
        "drupal/ajax_links_api": "^1.0",
        "drupal/backup_migrate": "^4.0",
        "drupal/barcodes": "^1.8",
        "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^3.0",
        "drupal/bootstrap": "^3.13",
        "drupal/bootstrap_layouts": "^5.1",
        "drupal/bootstrap_library": "^1.11",
        "drupal/business_rules": "^1.0",
        "drupal/captcha": "^1.0",
        "drupal/color_field": "^2.0",
        "drupal/conditional_fields": "^1.0",
        "drupal/config_split": "^1.3",
        "drupal/console": "^1.0.2",
        "drupal/core": "^8.6.0",
        "drupal/devel": "^1.2",
        "drupal/ds": "^3.1",
        "drupal/entity_reference_views_select": "^1.3",
        "drupal/eva": "^1.3",
        "drupal/field_group": "^3.0",
        "drupal/field_permissions": "^1.0",
        "drupal/fontawesome": "^2.9",
        "drupal/footable": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/group": "^1.0",
        "drupal/module_filter": "^3.1",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.2",
        "drupal/readonlymode": "^1.0",
        "drupal/reroute_email": "^1.0",
        "drupal/search_api": "^1.10",
        "drupal/simplify": "^1.0",
        "drupal/sms": "^1.1",
        "drupal/sms_simplegateway": "^1.1",
        "drupal/telephone_validation": "^2.1",
        "drupal/token": "^1.5",
        "drupal/toolbar_menu": "^2.1",
        "drupal/toolbar_menu_clean": "^1.0",
        "drupal/views_autorefresh_d8": "^1.1",
        "drupal/views_bootstrap": "^3.0",
        "drupal/views_conditional": "^1.0",
        "drupal/webform": "^5.0",
        "drush/drush": "^9.0.0",
        "jquery/image-picker": "0.3.0",
        "jquery/inputmask": "4.0.0",
        "jquery/intl-tel-input": "13.0.0",
        "jquery/rateit": "1.1.1",
        "jquery/select2": "4.0.5",
        "jquery/textcounter": "0.8.0",
        "jquery/timepicker": "1.11.13",
        "progress-tracker/progress-tracker": "1.4.0",
        "signature_pad/signature_pad": "2.3.0",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4",
        "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.0.0",
        "webmozart/path-util": "^2.3",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "webflo/drupal-core-require-dev": "^8.6.0"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
        ],
        "files": [
            "load.environment.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "web/modules/contrib/webform/composer.libraries.json"
            ]
        },
        "patchLevel": {
            "drupal/core": "-p2"
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library"
            ],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "drush/Commands/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ]
        },
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "initial": {
                ".editorconfig": "../.editorconfig",
                ".gitattributes": "../.gitattributes"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the output of composer why-not <package> ?

Comment: can you please specify what <package> you want to run the command why-not on !?

Comment: @Insasse
**composer why-not algolia/places**
drupal-composer/drupal-project  -  requires  algolia/places (1.10.0)

**composer why-not codemirror/codemirror**
drupal-composer/drupal-project  -  requires  codemirror/codemirror (5.40.0)

**composer why-not jquery/inputmask**
drupal-composer/drupal-project  -  requires  jquery/inputmask (4.0.0)

**composer why-not jquery/intl-tel-input**
drupal-composer/drupal-project  -  requires  jquery/intl-tel-input (13.0.0)

**composer why-not jquery/timepicker**
drupal-composer/drupal-project  -  requires  jquery/timepicker (1.11.13)

Comment: Why you need drupal-composer/drupal-project in your composer.json as required package? What if you remove that?

Comment: @Insasse my project was first installed using the composer command **composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev some_dir --stability dev --no-interaction** Please check the update of my question to see the content of my entire composer.json file, thank you

Comment: webforms should handle these packages on its own so you dont have to require them.
https://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/composer.libraries.json

Comment: @Insasse this exactly what was the problem, please answer correctly this question so I can mark it as the best answer! Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webforms should handle these packages on its own,
so you don't have to require them.

See: [cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/composer.libraries.json](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/composer.libraries.json)

In general if the package you required has its own `composer.json` require section you don't have to require them yourself.